# Play framework running long blocking tasks, without blocking the client

Tags: java, multithreading, akka, playframework-2.4

> The web client will be blocked while waiting for the response, but nothing will be blocked on the server, and server resources can be used to serve other clients.

Some of the client requests require my server to execute long blocking tasks. I understand that I can execute them in a separate thread pool.
But I also do not want the client to be blocked. I just want to return an immediate response to the client (e.g.  OK got your thick long blocking task). The client does not care about getting the result of the task execution it just needs to know that I am working on executing it.

**How I can implement this behavior in play?**

I think I can create a job queue and use another thread to process the job queue.  Where the play controller only adds the job to the queue and the other thread execute the jobs from the queue. Should I do that? Should I use Akka actor? (I do not know Akka I will need to learn it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Callbacks

It all started with the callbacks.

You have surely seen this:

```
Something.save(function(err) {  
  if (err)  {
    //error handling
    return;
  }
  console.log('success');
});
```

This is defining a callback in JavaScript - something which is going to be executed async. Thanks to their syntax, implementation and what-not, callbacks are not really your friend. Overusing them can lead to the dreaded **callback hell**

## Promises

In this context: Promises in ES6

```
Something.save()  
  .then(function() {
    console.log('success');
  })
  .catch(function() {
    //error handling
  })
```

Promises are not an 'ES6-thing', they have existed since many years, ES6 is bringing them to you. Promises are nice, you can even chain them:

```
saveSomething()  
  .then(updateOtherthing)
  .then(deleteStuff)  
  .then(logResults);
```

But enough with async for the insane.

## WebSocket

WebSocket is something I would recommend:

- as of today [very well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)
- wonderful support in Play 2.x
- full duplex TCP
- you finally can find time to learn Akka ;)

So you can create a client which opens a WebSocket connection to the Play application. On the server side you can [handle WebSocket connections either with Akka actors](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-actors) (which I recommend) or with callbacks on streams. Using actors is really easy and also fun - you define an Actor - and the moment someone opens a WebSocket connection, an instance of this actor is spawned and then every message you received in the WebSocket channel is going to be received by the actor - you can concentrate on your business logic without thinking about the surroundings and then send the message back - something Akka excels at.